# J2ME "Byte code exceeds 32K"

Tags: java, java-me

Why i get this error while compiling the Java file in J2ME.
Is it because extensive use of array Objects since i have a lots of array Objects defined in the Java file ?

Answer (score 3):

It might be an array initializer within a method, as in:

```
void someMethod() {
    int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3};
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int[] array = new int[4];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 2;
array[3] = 3;
```

and each element assignment takes four VM instructions (between 4 and 12 bytes of code per element.)

If the initializer is too long, it will exceed the 32K limit on the length of a method.

Comment: +1 yup agree. explained the something over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739180/j2me-byte-code-exceeds-32k/4739343#4739343)

Answer (score 0):

There is restriction with 32KB with method code, note that not with class file size.

Simple code

```
public void foo() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

will turn into [used [javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) to obtain this result]

```
public void foo();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   newarray int
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_0
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   iastore
   7:   dup
   8:   iconst_1
   9:   iconst_2
   10:  iastore
   11:  dup
   12:  iconst_2
   13:  iconst_3
   14:  iastore
   15:  astore_1
   16:  return
```

So you can imagine your huge & ocmplex array would turn into what size.

I suggest that you move your data into external resources in .jar file, it will also compress much better. also try optimizing it